# Undelete all files in EXT4 partitions on their original location

Tags: linux-mint, ext4, data-recovery

I accidently `rm -rf *`ed on my ext4 partition's root, and it deleted all files, of course. So, I immediately turned off the linux mint machine, modified /etc/fstab not to mount this drive, and booted. (It's not a boot partition & drive, so it might not be overwritten too much I guess?)

After reading some SO/SE questions and answers, I ran `sudo ext4magic /dev/sdd -a $(date -d "-120hours" +%s)` and luckily, It shows list of all files I accidently deleted!

The problem is, I don't have any left HDD to store all the recovered files on drive. I have to restore all files in same drive, so I cannot use `ext4magic /dev/sdd -r` as this will recover files at `./RECOVERDIR/` and it's not big enough to store all files.

Is there any way to restore all files in place on a drive where accident happened? I am worring that I can mess it more if I do it wrong so I am asking here.

PS. It's the only partition on HDD.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is No.  If you don't have a another fs with enough space, either local to the machine or on your network, your only option is to buy another drive large enough to hold the files you want to recover.  e.g. a USB drive (which will also make a handy backup device once you've finished using it for this purpose).  You can find these as self-contained external drives, or as USB drive docks that you can insert & remove drives to/from as needed (and some have two or more "slots" for drives in the one dock).  The former is convenient and simple, the latter is more flexible.